# Python. Библиотека socket метод readlines() возвращает только одну позицию

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp-ip

Добрых суток.

Пытаюсь читать сокет с помощью файла, который создаётся методом `connection.makefile("r")`.

Я ожидаю получить список с количеством указанных позиций.

```
s = b"string\r\nstring\r\nstring\r\nstring\r\nstring\r\nstring\r\nstring\r\n"  # семь строк
# отправляю строку на сервер

# на сервере
file_read = connection.makefile("r", newline="\r\n")
lines = file_read.readlines(6)  # здесь получаю: ["string\r\n"]
# хотя ожидаю такой список ["string", "string", "string", ...]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, или что я не понимаю. В сети ответа не нашёл.

Comment: А как вы ожидаете такой список, если сами говорите методу `readlines()` считать 6 байт из файла? Делайте тогда уж цикл и используйте `readline()`, наверное.

Comment: @strawdog, вы правы. А я думал, что нужно строки указывать. Тогда непонятно как в сокетах этот метод использовать, так как если указывать больше поступившего количества, то он будет ждать остальные данные.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону socket/receive (`socket.recv()`), так как он считает буфер такого размера, какой вы укажете. Есть еще вариант сначала отдавать сообщение фиксированной длины с указанием длины следующего сообщения с передаваемыми данными. Либо, используя метод file.read() указывать какой-нибудь заранее оговоренный символ конца передачи данных.

Comment: @strawdog, благодарю, за ответы. Очень помогли разобраться. В моём случае только по символам конца строки можно определяться, поэтому, учитывая перечисленные вами варианты, выбрал способ чтения с сокета с помощью '.readline(),'.

Comment: @strawdog, вы правильно указали на ошибку. Если ответите через форму, то я смогу отметить ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы говорите методу readlines() считать 6 байт из файла.

Я бы посоветовал смотреть в сторону socket/receive (`socket.recv()`), так как он считает буфер такого размера, какой вы укажете. Есть еще вариант сначала отдавать сообщение фиксированной длины с указанием длины следующего сообщения с передаваемыми данными. Либо, используя метод `file.read()` указывать какой-нибудь заранее оговоренный символ конца передачи данных.